# Multiple FK poiting to single column

Tags: database-design, foreign-key

I'm working on a project, I'm not an advanced backend/database dev, but I always like to understand the 'why's, pros and cons' of things. So I have this table and some times I use Foreign Keys to relate one table to another.

One thing my client asked me recently was to implement a way to know wich user created each record on the table. Doesn't matter if it's a product, category, address, purchase, client, whatever. He wants to know who created those records.

To do that, I implemented one more field on these tables and I called it `author_id`, this id is reference the id on the main user table.

The problem is, If I go to the table `tb_product` and create one FK pointing to tb_user.id I can't do the same on the `tb_category`. Same applies to all the other tables that are referencing the user ID to be the author of that record.

I could go around this issue by changing the name of the following FK declarations, ex:

- fk_product_author_id
- fk_category_author_id
- fk_address_author_id
- and so on...

But my question is.. Is it ok to do that? Is it the correct way to declare all those fk? Or should I do something completely different?

Comment: The names need to be unique at database level. So your idea is just fine, but there are plenty other available.

Comment: Search for `SQL style guide` - there are many - pick one that suits you and **STICK** to it!

Comment: @R.Hoek, this varies between DBMS, some products requires the constraint name to be unique at table level and therefor allows the same name to be reused between tables.

Comment: I agree what others have said, and whatever you do dont let the database generate the name for you. It will become a nightmare when maintaining the schema.

Comment: Since the database was preventing me from adding the same reference, I tought i was doing something wrong, even if I was able to use with another name. But based on the comments and answers, I think it's just the way it works. Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

You should choose a pattern for the FK name that respects the relationships between the tables.

My preference is `FK_<child entity>_<verb phrase>_<parent entity>`.

So `fk_product_modified_by_user`, `fk_category_modified_by_user`, etc.

Comment: Nice and simple method to name and remember how to name it.

Answer (score 1):

Enforcing relationship between entities with foreign key constraints is [almost] always the right thing to do. So you're absolute correct about adding foreign keys.

Naming itself is very subjective topic; in my opinion , consistency in naming DB objects is the most import thing.  If you're working on existing project, maybe it is not a bad idea to ask DBA for naming convention used in your organization.  DB engine itself doesn't care what style is used.

If there is no standard in place yet, pick something and stick to it.  More importantly, document the naming rules , so other people in the team follow them as well.